# If statement inside for loops

Tags: java

```
for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
        if (i % 13 == 0) {
            System.out.println("#: " + i);
        }
    }
```

I just started learning java yesterday and I'm stuck with for loops statement.
I'm confused about part

```
if (i % 13 == 0)
```

variable i is initialized to zero **int i = 0** and if you divide zero  by 13 the result is 0. There's no remainder. I tried on calculator.
But when I run the program. I get the result like this it keeps adding by 13 how?

```
#: 0
#: 13
#: 26
#: 39
#: 52
#: 65
#: 78
#: 91
#: 104
#: 117
#: 130
#: 143
```

Comment: Well, what is the remainder when you divide 13 by 13 (the second line in your output)?

Comment: your porgram will print i everytime a i is divisible by 13, what is your question exactly?

Comment: what are you trying to do? what do you think `i % 13` is doing?

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is correct; it does appear to be adding 13 every time because your `if` statement is effectively saying, in plain english:

> Display the value of i whenever 13 divides i evenly (leaving no remainder)

So indeed, each of the numbers you're seeing divides evenly, leaving no remainder:

```
#: 0   //   0 / 13 = 0, no remainder
#: 13  //  13 / 13 = 1, no remainder
#: 26  //  26 / 13 = 2, no remainder
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1):

The results you are seeing are all of the numbers between 0 and 150 (which you specified on this line: `for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {`) that are multiples (have no remainder) of 13

Answer (score 1):

The first loop adds 1 to the `int i` for each iteration. It will then check if there is a remainder when divided by 13:

```
(i % 13 == 0)
```

Finally, it will print that number if it doesn't have a remainder when divided by 13:

```
System.out.println("#: " + i);
```

So the result is essentially all the numbers that are multiples of 13 between 0 and 150.